# Present a viewcontroller in UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to present a `ViewController` in a `UIView` of another `ViewController` with top to bottom animation. Height of `UIView` is half of the superview and after presenting another `ViewController` in the `UIView` the interaction of the another half part of `ViewController` should be enable for the user. Please help me if anyone is having any idea about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you add the the small VC's view at the bottom of the other VC and animate the small VC's view till middle of the parent VC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To add a view controller to another view controller, you can do the following:

Inside the parent view controller class:

```
addChildViewController(someViewController)
view.addSubview(someViewController.view)
someViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
someViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Then, set the layout constraints to position the view controller:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    someViewController.view.leadingAnchor .constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor ),
    someViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    someViewController.view.bottomAnchor  .constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor  ),
    someViewController.view.topAnchor     .constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor     )
])
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: This worked for me.. Animation is not there but this is working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding the animation: you could just move the view out of the screen and then animate it in